# How to validate radio in specific jquery validation structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

Hello i'm at coding a multi step form , and have different parts of form divided with a jquery script with the `<fieldset> </fieldset>` tag

My form validation runs on that script to and look like this

```
$(".next").click(function(){

  var erros = 0;
    //error checking in the first fieldset
  if (fieldsetn == 1) {
    //verify name
      if ($('input[name="name"]').val().length ===0){
           $('input[name="name"]').attr("placeholder","Please enter your name");
              $('input[name="name"]').addClass('warning');


        erros = 1;
    }
    else {
    $('input[name="name"]').removeClass('warning');
    }
    //verify surname
    if ($('input[name="surname"]').val().length ===0){
         $('input[name="surname"]').attr("placeholder","Please enter your surname");
          $('input[name="surname"]').addClass('warning');

        erros = 1;
    }
    else {
    $('input[name="surname"]').removeClass('warning');
    }
```

But yet i have a problem validating a radio field set my radio field loks like this:

```
 Chose the Logo pack <a href="services.html"  style="float:right" target="_blank">More Information about Logo Packs Pleas click here</a> 
                        <div id="emotion" name="emotion">
    <input type="radio" name="emotion" id="basi" />
        <label for="basi"><img src="images/basi.jpg" width="630px" alt="I'm sad" /></label><br>

         <input type="radio" name="emotion" id="deli" />
        <label for="deli"><img src="images/deli.jpg" width="630px" alt="I'm sad" /></label><br>

    <input type="radio" name="emotion" id="premi" />
        <label for="premi"><img src="images/premi.jpg" width="630px" alt="I'm happy" /></label>
</div>
```

How to validate my radio field set in that jquery validate code structure so that one option must be selected ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try this-

```
if($('input[name="emotion"]:checked').length==0)
{
  alert("Please select radio button");
}
```

or

```
if(!$('input[name="emotion"]:checked').length)
{
  alert("Please select radio button");
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tqzzdu21/1/)

Comment: i have one question though as soon as i click on the next button on my 2th form to come to the form with the radios in mention it alerts me can we make it so that only if i click on the submit or next button to alert me not in the start of form 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
 if($('input[type="radio"][name="emotion"]').is(':checked')) 
 { 
      alert("it's checked"); 
 }else{
      alert("it's not checked"); 
 }
```

Comment: yes this option work to thank you Yatin Mistry and have a nice day :)

Answer (score -1):

```
if($('input[name="emotion"]:checked').length==0)
{
  alert("Please select radio button");
}
```

This work to

```
if(!$('input[name="emotion"]:checked').length)
{
  alert("Please select radio button");
}
```